# Alexa Skill response is showing nothing when doing in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Stuck from day. Problem is like this.

```
var alexa = require('alexa-app');

// Define an alexa-app
var myapp = new alexa.app('myapp');

myapp.intent('WelcomeIntent', function(request,response) {
    console.log(request);
    response.say("This  is not working.<break time='2s'/>")
    setTimeout(function(){
            response.say("This  is inside timeout.")
    },1000);
});
```

On the Speech Simulator Amazon Alexa the output look like this.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "SSML",
      "ssml": "<speak>This is not working.<break time='2s'/></speak>"
    },
    "shouldEndSession": false
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

Please help me out. Problem is the response inside the asynchronous function like  Promise or setTimeout or fetch or google map API I am not getting the proper response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I figure out the solution.

To handle async callback in the alexa-app framework there are two way.

## Using version below 4.0.0

```
var alexa = require('alexa-app');

// Define an alexa-app
var myapp = new alexa.app('myapp');

myapp.intent('WelcomeIntent', function(request,response) {
    console.log(request);
    makePromiseBasedCallback(request,response);
    return false;
});
makePromiseBasedCallback.then(function(data){
    response.say(data.cardContent);
    response.send();
});
```

## Using version 4.0.0

follow the github [link](https://github.com/alexa-js/alexa-app/issues/235)

Comment: Do you have the code for when using version 4.0.0...? The "you must return a promise" stuff. I am fairly new to Alexa apps. I am getting the response from the GET request(on console), but its not saying it.

Comment: Okay so you need to return promise object and then of promise do your say or reprompt with session alive

Comment: cool. Great you will learn a lot in alexa app development. Use the latest reference document where you can even modulate alexa tone and great stuff into it.